# How do I run a non-android-emulating Java program using the Android Time library android.text.format.Time?

Tags: java, android, junit, noclassdeffounderror

I want to run a JUnit test that uses `android.text.format.Time`, but when I try to add android.jar to the classpath, I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!", [because android.jar contains only stub implementation of the classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8983031/1112765).

How do I run a normal Java program and use the Time library `android.text.format.Time`?

Comment: Have you looked at [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org)?

Comment: @Ben - Can I use Robolectric without Maven?

Comment: I believe so. There's some discussion of that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906930/is-anyone-out-there-using-robolectric-without-maven-on-intellij).